# £ character in XML

Tags: xml, delphi, txmldocument

Using Delphi XE2 TXMLDocument and MSXML

```
<description>£1.00 x 100</description>   parsing error as does
<description><![CDATA[£1.00 x 100]]></description>   parsing error as does
```

The £ character is not noted as an invalid character.

Is this an issue?
More importantly what workaround is suggested.

TIA

Ephraim

Comment: What encoding are you using for this text? The XML looks valid to me, so I can only guess that you are not using a proper text encoding.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Sorry, but there's something else going on here. I just tested with `<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<root>
  <description>£1.00 x 100</description>
</root>` and it parses absolutely fine.

Comment: @KenWhite Try saving your file as ANSI and then see what happens

Comment: @David: I understand that; the poster said the file was UTF-8 and wouldn't parse, and I pointed out that was wrong because what I tried successfully parsed. (I tried what the poster said wouldn't work, and it worked perfectly well.) If it doesn't parse, it's because the declaration doesn't match the format; it's not because the pound symbol is invalid.

Comment: @Ken  The asker said that the declaration specified UTF-8. The file is surely not UTF-8.

Comment: @David: Where did I say it *was*? You're quibbling over my pointing out that the poster had misdiagnosed the problem. *The poster said* it was UTF-8, right above my comment. I *never said* the file was UTF-8. I said that *if the file was UTF-8, there was another problem*.

Comment: @Ken I was confused by "the poster said the file was UTF-8".

Answer (score 6):

The likely explanation for this is that you have specified UTF-8 in your `?xml` declaration but have actually encoded the file using ANSI. Obviously the solution is to encode the file correctly as UTF-8.

Comment: Using notepad++ I saved the file with utf-9 encoding and no longer need the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

```
&#x00A3;
```

is a workaround

```
<description>&#x00A3;1.00 x 100</description>
```

Comment: This might side step the problem but almost certainly you are just suppressing a much deeper problem. Rather than moving forward with this workaround you should find and address the real problem.